# Deriving the probability distribution function of the cross-spectral phase

Tags: phase, probability-distribution-function, derivation

I came across a research paper (\ref{Ref 1}) where the probability distribution of the phase of the cross-spectrum was derived. Unfortunately, I could not understand how the authors arrived at the final expression. The derivation process went as follows. The Fourier spectra of the two measured signals, ${{X}_{1}}\left( f \right)$ and ${{X}_{2}}\left( f \right)$ are assumed to be jointly Gaussian, and their joint pdf is given as

$$
p\left( \mathbf{X}|\mathbf{Q} \right)=\frac{1}{{{\pi }^{2}}\left| \mathbf{Q} \right|}\exp \left\{ -{{\mathbf{X}}^{H}}{{\mathbf{Q}}^{-1}}\mathbf{X} \right\} \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
where $ \mathbf{X}\left( f \right)={{\left[ {{X}_{1}}\left( f \right),{{X}_{2}}\left( f \right) \right]}^{T}} $ represents the vector of the autospectra at frequency $f$, $\mathbf{Q}\left( f \right)=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {{q}_{11}}\left( f \right) & {{q}_{12}}\left( f \right)  \\
   q_{12}^{*}\left( f \right) & {{q}_{22}}\left( f \right)  \\
\end{matrix} \right] $ is the cross-covariance matrix, and ${{q}_{ij}}\left( f \right)=E\left\{ {{X}_{i}}\left( f \right)X_{j}^{*}\left( f \right) \right\}$ is the power (or cross-power) spectral density. The superscripts $^{*}$, $^{T}$, and $^{H}$ denote complex conjugate, transpose, and Hermitian  transpose, respectively, while $E\left\{ \cdot  \right\}$ denote the mathematical expectation operation. The frequency index $f$ is omitted in Equation $\ref{1}$ and subsequent equations below for simplicity.
If the signals are represented in polar form, $\mathbf{X}={{\left[ {{X}_{1}},{{X}_{2}} \right]}^{T}}={{\left[ {{y}_{1}}{{e}^{j{{\theta }_{1}}}},{{y}_{2}}{{e}^{j{{\theta }_{2}}}} \right]}^{T}}$, then the joint pdf can be expressed as

$$
p\left( {{y}_{1}},{{y}_{2}},\theta  \right)=\frac{{{y}_{1}}{{y}_{2}}}{{{\pi }^{2}}\left| \mathbf{Q} \right|}\exp \left\{ \frac{2{{y}_{1}}{{y}_{2}}\operatorname{Re}\left\{ q_{12}^{*}{{e}^{j\theta }} \right\}-{{q}_{22}}y_{1}^{2}-{{q}_{11}}y_{2}^{2}}{\left| \mathbf{Q} \right|} \right\} \tag{2}\label{2}
$$

where $\theta ={{\theta }_{2}}-{{\theta }_{1}}$. Then by change of variables and marginalisation, it can be shown that

$$
{{p}_{\mu }}\left( \theta  \right)=\frac{1-{{\mu }^{2}}}{2\pi \left( 1-{{\mu }^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\theta  \right)}\left[ 1+\frac{\arccos \left( -\mu \cos \theta  \right)\mu \cos \theta }{\sqrt{1-{{\mu }^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\theta }} \right] \tag{3}\label{3}
$$

where $\mu \left( f \right)=\frac{\left| {{q}_{12}}\left( f \right) \right|}{\sqrt{{{q}_{11}}\left( f \right){{q}_{22}}\left( f \right)}}$ is the magnitude of the coherence between the two signals.

My questions are as follows:

1. How can the expression in Equation $($\ref{2}$)$ be correctly expressed in terms of the coherence $\mu $? I tried by substituting ${{q}_{11}}=E\left\{ {{X}_{1}}X_{1}^{*} \right\}=E\left\{ y_{1}^{2} \right\}$, ${{q}_{22}}=E\left\{ {{X}_{2}}X_{2}^{*} \right\}=E\left\{ y_{2}^{2} \right\}$, $q_{12}^{*}=\left| {{q}_{12}} \right|{{e}^{j{{\theta }_{12}}}}=\mu \sqrt{{{q}_{11}}{{q}_{22}}}{{e}^{j{{\theta }_{12}}}}$, and $\left| \mathbf{Q} \right|={{q}_{11}}{{q}_{22}}-q_{12}^{*}{{q}_{12}}={{q}_{11}}{{q}_{22}}-{{\left| {{q}_{12}} \right|}^{2}}=\left( 1-{{\mu }^{2}} \right){{q}_{11}}{{q}_{22}}$ to get

$$
\begin{align}
  & p\left( {{y}_{1}},{{y}_{2}},\theta  \right)=\frac{{{y}_{1}}{{y}_{2}}}{{{\pi }^{2}}\left( 1-{{\mu }^{2}} \right){{q}_{11}}{{q}_{22}}}\exp \left\{ \frac{2{{y}_{1}}{{y}_{2}}\operatorname{Re}\left\{ \mu \sqrt{{{q}_{11}}{{q}_{22}}}{{e}^{j{{\theta }_{12}}}}{{e}^{j\theta }} \right\}-y_{1}^{2}E\left\{ y_{2}^{2} \right\}-y_{2}^{2}E\left\{ y_{1}^{2} \right\}}{\left( 1-{{\mu }^{2}} \right){{q}_{11}}{{q}_{22}}} \right\}\\ 
 & \hspace{2cm}=\frac{{{y}_{1}}{{y}_{2}}}{{{\pi }^{2}}\left( 1-{{\mu }^{2}} \right)E\left\{ y_{1}^{2} \right\}E\left\{ y_{2}^{2} \right\}}\exp \left\{ \frac{2{{y}_{1}}{{y}_{2}}\operatorname{Re}\left\{ \mu \sqrt{E\left\{ y_{1}^{2} \right\}E\left\{ y_{2}^{2} \right\}}{{e}^{j{{\theta }_{12}}}}{{e}^{j\theta }} \right\}-y_{1}^{2}E\left\{ y_{2}^{2} \right\}-y_{2}^{2}E\left\{ y_{1}^{2} \right\}}{\left( 1-{{\mu }^{2}} \right)E\left\{ y_{1}^{2} \right\}E\left\{ y_{2}^{2} \right\}} \right\} \\ 
\end{align} \tag{4}\label{4}
$$
If I assume $E\left\{ y_{1}^{2} \right\}=y_{1}^{2}$, $E\left\{ y_{2}^{2} \right\}=y_{2}^{2}$, and ${{\theta }_{12}}=E\left\{ \theta  \right\}=\theta $ (I understand these are not valid assumptions unless the quantities are constant, but this is the only way I could think of to simplify the expression further), then I end up with
$$
p\left( {{y}_{1}},{{y}_{2}},\theta  \right)=\frac{1}{{{\pi }^{2}}\left( 1-{{\mu }^{2}} \right){{y}_{1}}{{y}_{2}}}\exp \left\{ \frac{2\left( \mu \cos 2\theta -1 \right)}{\left( 1-{{\mu }^{2}} \right)} \right\} \tag{5}\label{5}
$$

which definitely does not look correct. This is confirmed by the fact that taking the marginal pdf for $\theta $ as

$$
p\left( \theta  \right)=\int\limits_{0 }^{\infty }{\int\limits_{0 }^{\infty }{\frac{1}{{{\pi }^{2}}\left( 1-{{\mu }^{2}} \right){{y}_{1}}{{y}_{2}}}\exp \left\{ \frac{2\left( \mu \cos 2\theta -1 \right)}{\left( 1-{{\mu }^{2}} \right)} \right\}}}{{d}_{{{y}_{1}}}}{{d}_{{{y}_{2}}}} \tag{6}\label{6}
$$
does not give the same result as in the paper. How do I proceed correctly?

2. Why did the authors use change of variables before marginalisation? The pdf $p\left( {{y}_{1}},{{y}_{2}},\theta  \right)$ in Equation (\ref{2}) is already directly dependent on $\theta $; doesn’t that make a change of variables unnecessary? Unless the marginal probability obtained in Equation (\ref{3}) is actually that of ${{p}_{\mu }}\left( \theta  \right)=p\left( \mu \cos \theta  \right)$, which is different from the pdf of interest, $p\left( \theta  \right)$. I read  ${{p}_{\mu }}\left( \theta  \right)$ as the pdf of $\theta $ conditioned on the coherence $\mu $. Is that the correct way to interpret the notation  ${{p}_{\mu }}\left( \theta  \right)$? Unfortunately, there was no description of the notation adopted in the research paper.

Thank you for your help. I asked this question previously in Math because I think the question is primarily about the process of mathematical derivation rather than signal processing concepts. However, I did not get any reply, so I decided to ask in DSP instead.

References

$\tag{Ref 1}\label{Ref 1} $ B. Lee, A. Said, T. Kalker and R. W. Schafer, "Maximum Likelihood Time Delay Estimation with Phase Domain Analysis in the Generalized Cross Correlation Framework," 2008 Hands-Free Speech Communication and Microphone Arrays, 2008, pp. 89-92, doi: 10.1109/HSCMA.2008.4538695.